# How do I write a "predict" function with python/pytorch for an image classifier

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch

I'm writing a "predict" function with python/pytorch for an image classifier, and I'm not sure how to resolve this error:

RuntimeError: expected stride to be a single integer value or a list of 1 values to match the convolution dimensions, but got stride=[1, 1]

Here's a link to the entire .ipynb notebook file:

https://github.com/willdata0101/Udacity/blob/master/Image%20Classifier%20Project%20(1).ipynb

I need to return the top 5 probabilities and classes for a certain image. I'm not sure how. This is the code that I'm having trouble with:

```
def predict(image, model, topk=5):
''' Predict the class (or classes) of an image using a trained deep learning model.
'''
# TODO: Implement the code to predict the class from an image file

image_tensor = pil_loader(image)
image_tensor = test_transforms(image_tensor).float()
input = Variable(image_tensor)
input = input.to(device)
output = model.forward(input)
output = torch.exp(output)
probs, classes = output.topk(topk, dim=1)
return probs, classes

class_to_idx = {v:k for k,v in class_to_idx.iteritems()}

for idx in class_to_idx:
    classes.append(class_to_idx[idx])
```

image = test_dir + '/1/image_06743.jpg'

probs, classes = predict(image, model)

Comment: Can you post the structure of your model?

Comment: It seems you haven't added batch dimension, try doing `input=input.unsqueeze(0)` before passing it to model.